# Does memcached send packets that fragment on IP layer using UDP and not TCP?

Tags: memcached, fragmentation, mtu, ip-fragmentation, mss

question is in title.

I have read that memcached fragments only on application layer for large responses.
Is this always the case?
If TCP is not used e.g. client -> a.b.c.d:UDP/11211 ; a.b.c.d:UDP/11211 -> client,
**how can the memcached server know the PathMTU to ensure that there is no IP-Fragmentation?**

Does it silently check the path with PMTUD and TCP?

Thanks in advance,
The Dude